# Image not loading in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to load an image from my project's local storage in email with Thymeleaf but it won't !

```html
    <img src="../static/img/logo.png" alt="MyPicture" th:src="@{img/logo.png}">
```

although when I try with an absolute path it's perfectly loading

```html
    <img src="C:/Workspace/myProject/src/main/resources/static/img/logo.png" alt="MyPicture">
```

My images are stored in `static/img`

[image: project tree here]

Comment: did you try static/img/logo.png ??

Comment: yes it's not working either

Answer (score 0):

The image path shall start with a forward slash like

```
<img alt="MyPicture" th:src="@{/img/logo.png}">
```

Comment: it raises an exception saying : org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/img/logo.png" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "password-forgot-email" - line 59, col 22)

Comment: Try with classpath prefix like `th:src="@{classpath:img/logo.png}`

Answer (score -1):

try changing your path to

```
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="MyPicture">
```

and you might also want to invalidate cache from your IDE settings for the image to be detected